# Unexpected firing when trying to set .click() handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append an event to a link's click handler. I can select the element by its `href` element, but when I enter the following code into the Javascript console, the event is triggered, rather than having an event handler added:

`$('a[href="example.com"]')[0].click(console.log("Message"))`

I've read through [the docs for .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/), which state that calling `.click` with an argument shouldn't trigger the event, and am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to call `.click()` of `HTMLELement` which doesn't exist.

When you do `[some number]` on `jQuery` object, the corresponding `HTMLElement` will be returned. But `.click()` is a function of `jQuery` and not of `HTMLElement`. Also you should wrap your code in an anonymous function.

Do this:

```
$('a[href="example.com"]').click(function(){
    console.log("Message")
});
```

Using HTMLELement, you would do this:

```
$('a[href="example.com"]')[0].onclick =  function(){
  console.log("Message")
}
```

But I don't recommend the above approach. Just saying that the above exists too.

Comment: Ah ok. I guess I was misunderstanding the JQuery selector, I thought it worked the same as getElementsByName, where it returns an array that you have to select from. Why is the bottom option not recommended? Is it because it might overwrite rather than append event handlers?

Comment: @wils484 you're right. But another reason is when you load jQuery, you load it to make your work easier and efficient. So why not use use jQuery when it is loaded :)

Answer (score 2):

You forget to write the function, you need to wrap code in function. Try this,

```
$('a[href="example.com"]').click(function(){console.log("Message")})
```

Click is an event of jQuery so when you select element by $ it returns jquery object and you can call further jquery event on that object. but when you write `[0]` it returns DOM element and that has no click event handler.